# Microsoft Teams crashes since a few days when using Canon EOS webcam utility

Tags: drivers, webcam, camera, microsoft-teams

## Problem

Until last week Microsoft Teams worked in combination with the [EOS webcam utility](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/self-help-center/eos-webcam-utility/) and my Canon EOS camera.
Since today, every meeting I start with my camera on results in a crash of Microsoft Teams with the following error message:

> There was a glitch. Sorry for the inconvenience. Please sign in again.

I'm using:

- Windows 10 `v1909`
- Teams version `1.3.00.30866 (64-bit)`
- EOS webcam utility version `1.0`
- Canon EOS 550D<sup>1</sup>

## What I've tried

- Using Teams in the Edge browser in combination with my EOS camera, this *does* work.
- Using different meeting software in the browser (Jitsi), this *does* work.
- Removing the cache files, per [this MS Answers post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/msteams_tfe-msteams_meeting-msteams_audio/ms-teams-crashes-when-eos-webcam-utility-is-used/e90d390e-f447-494a-9960-81a6bb359539), this *did not* solve anything.
- Restarting my machine, this *did not* solve anything.
- Updating EOS webcam utility to version `1.1`

## Question

How can I get MS Teams working again with my Canon EOS camera, through the EOS webcam utility?

---

<sub>1: This camera is not officially supported by the EOS webcam utility, but it has been working flawlessly until now. Also, the fact that other software (e.g. the browser) still can use this camera as a webcam signals to me that this is not the issue.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since at least version `1.4.00.4167` the EOS webcam utility version 1.1 works again as it should and the issue is no longer present.

For version `1.3.00.30866` apparently this is a known issue, as the [Canon page](https://archive.org/details/eoswebcam-utility-beta-win-0.9.0) mentions in a footnote:

[image: Canon mentions that Teams v1.3.00.30866 does not work with the EOS webcam utility]

On the [7th page of this MS answers thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/msteams_tfe-msteams_meeting-msteams_audio/ms-teams-crashes-when-eos-webcam-utility-is-used/e90d390e-f447-494a-9960-81a6bb359539?page=7) I found an alternative to the Canon suggested workaround: using the beta version of the EOS webcam utility solves this issue.

After I installed webcam utility `v0.9.0` (I found an upload [here](https://archive.org/details/eoswebcam-utility-beta-win-0.9.0)), everything worked again as it should.